# KeepAliveTimeout 0 in apache webserver

Tags: apache, centos, httpd.conf

I am running apache webserver in centos 7. Configured KeepAliveTimeout 0 in httpd.conf file.
I thought based on this configuration, every tcp connection is alive until we force close. but count is gradually decreased when application is idle.

then what is  KeepAliveTimeout 0  meant by.? what do i need to change for TCP connection alive..?

For reference i have attached screenshot of the server

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click F12[DeveloperTools] in browser and go to Network Tab. Now reload the web page and check request headers & response headers. You should see keep alive parametre in both headers.

Comment: yes. i can see from both headers. but my question is when we set keepalive =0, Is all tcp connections active until we force closed or it will be auto close    once session expired..?

Comment: sessios will be auto closed once the session get expires.

Answer (score 0):

Client must request KeepAlive, setting it just in the server does not force client connections to use keepalive.

Comment: How browser concludes here the request should (get method) be keepalive or non-keepalive

Comment: @Sunny in a request header called "Connection", only valid for http/1.1 iirc.